# Numerous multiple regressions, changing one variable each time

Tags: r

I have basic R code for running a multiple regression:

fit <- lm(`cold` ~ `breed` + `gender` + `237`, data=rweights)

However, I want to run this code multiple times with a slight tweak each time. Where it says '237' (a column title), that can be any number from 1 - 1000  (also column titles) and I want to run the multiple regression for every column. So I want it to run the equivalent of:

fit <- lm(`var1` ~ `var2` + `var3` + `1`, data=rweights)

fit <- lm(`var1` ~ `var2` + `var3` + `2`, data=rweights)

....

fit <- lm(`var1` ~ `var2` + `var3` + `1000`, data=rweights)

I then intend to analyse the results of these many multiple regressions, so ideally there would be a nice output that collates it all, but I appreciate that's maybe a whole other issue! Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have column names that are just numbers? I don't think those are valid names. Do you mean they have the form `X237`?

Comment: They're just numbers, but it works fine in the sample code I gave so long as I put a ` around them. Not sure if it is a larger problem though?

Comment: Maybe not, but I suspect the backtick will keep showing up. And if you're fine with that, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I'm hoping it's just a quick one off thing (although it's proving to be far more complex than I envisaged), but I'll certainly bear it in mind for the future - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code that should help you get started:

```
### Generate fake data
n = 1000
var1 = rnorm(n)
var2 = rnorm(n)
var3 = rnorm(n)
k = 10
dat = data.frame(var1, var2, var3, matrix(runif(n*k), n, k))

### Object where all the fitted models are stored
mods = rep(list(NULL), k)

### Loop through the different models
for (i in 1:k){
    form = paste0("var1 ~ var2 + var3 + X", i)
    mods[[i]] = lm(as.formula(form), data = dat)
    }

### Examples
summary(mods[[1]])
summary(mods[[2]])
```

---

As suggested by Tom Haddow in the comments, one way you can generalize this is using `colnames`:

```
mods = rep(list(NULL), k)

# Get column names, remove the ones you don't want to loop through
varlist = colnames(dat)[-(1:3)]

for (i in 1:k){
    form = paste0("var1 ~ var2 + var3 + ", varlist[i])
    mods[[i]] = lm(as.formula(form), data = dat)
    }
summary(mod[[1]])
```

or even

```
mods = rep(list(NULL), k)
varlist = colnames(dat)[-(1:3)]

for (v in varlist){
    form = paste0("var1 ~ var2 + var3 + ", v)
    mods[[v]] = lm(as.formula(form), data = dat)
    }
summary(mods$X1)
```

with the only difference being how you would access the elements in `mods`.

Comment: Thanks for this I ran your dummy, which worked, and tried to transfer the principle to my own data. Can't say I had much luck though. I think my issue is knowing which parts of your script I should replace with my own. I assume I can ignore the entire top park for generating fake data...?

If so, then 'k' won't work further on, I also have no idea what k seems to be for. 

I need to buck up my R skills.

Comment: `k` is comparable to your `1000` columns, I just used a smaller number. So you could try `k=1000` or more generally, `k=NCOL(rweight)` (possibly subtracting extra columns.

Comment: It is mentioned in the question that there are some variables given as names. Would it be an idea to create a variable list to loop through rather than using the loop to paste the number? Something along the lines of  `varlist <- as.character(1:1000)` 
`varlist <- paste0("X",varlist)`
`varlist <- c("foo", "bar", varlist)` and then change your for loop to `for (i in varlist){`

Comment: Thanks @TomHaddow, I edited the answer to include a more general approach based on your idea.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Having to give up on it today and will decide again tomorrow if I keep trying or not. Admittedly it's far more complex than I would have imagined it would be.

Comment: Good luck. By the way, if you're primarily interested in doing variable selection, you might be interested in the `step` function.

Comment: We ended up with:

`r.sqr <- matrix(NA, nrow =1, ncol = length(6:ncol(rweights)))
 
 for(i in 6:ncol(rweights)){
   na.n <- length(which(is.na(as.numeric(unlist(rweights[,i])))))
   if (na.n == nrow(rweights)) next
 nn <- which(!is.na(as.numeric(unlist(rweights[,i]))))
   if (is.na(unlist(rweights[nn,2])) && is.na(unlist(rweights[nn,4]))) next
   fit <- lm(Cold~ Breed + Gender + as.numeric(unlist(rweights[,i])), data=rweights, , na.action=na.omit)
   r.sqr[1,(i-5)] <- summary(fit)$r.squared
 }`

This gave R2 in a nice table. But we couldn't manage to get a p-value table sadly.

Comment: You can get p-values with `summary(fit)[[4]]`, this will give the estimates, standard errors, t-values, and p-values. For p-value specifically, you can do `summary(fit)[[4]][,4]`.